# ¿Cómo cambiar URL sin recargar la página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, ajax

Soy relativamente nuevo en programación web y quisiera saber como cambiar la URL y recargar solo una sección de la página, de tal forma que se guarde un historial y pueda darle al botón de volver en los navegadores y que vaya al contenido anterior.

Lo que he hecho es actualizar una sección con JS, pero claro, no cambia la URL y sin esto, cuando intento volver atrás lo que hago es salir de la página o cuando refresco simplemente va al inicio que definí y no donde estaba el usuario.

Básicamente quisiera saber como solucionar ese problema, ya sea con framework u otro método que sea (de preferencia) independiente del lenguaje orientado al servidor que use (generalmente es Java o PHP).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cambiar la url sin recargar la pagina puedes usar:

```
history.pushState(null, "", "urlACambiar");
```

Eso es solo si por algun extraño motivo deseas cambiar la URL sin enviar datos y sin recargar la pagina, en caso de que quieras enviar datos checa el siguiente formulario:

```html
<form action="" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="texto" id="">
    <input type="checkbox" name="terminos">

    <input type="submit" value="sub">
</form>
```

OJO ten en cuenta que el **method es get** y solo por get se puede hacer lo propuesto, tambien que **get si recarga la pagina**, sin embargo la recarga y añade los datos por URL, sin embargo la diferencia entre `get` y `post`, es que con `get` el usuario puede volver atras sin problemas, es decir, se crea un historial que guarda el estado de las paginas, por lo que sí, tu pagina si le das atras mantendra su estado, ahora bien, por post la pagina no enviara datos por la URL (la url no va a cambiar, pero la pagina siempre te preguntara que para poder volver atras deberas volver a enviar los datos que ya habias enviado), el tipico `confirmar reenvio de formulario` del que nos advierten los navegadores.

Te mostraria como hacer esto mismo con ajax, pero por lo que veo ajax no cambia la url (hice pruebas y vi que la url no cambiaba aunque usara el metodo get), así que si realmente quieres que cambie la url para que tengas disponible un historial, entonces deberias usar alguna de las opciones anteriores.